# Shindig maven install: Gadget Renderer faild

Tags: maven, installation, apache-shindig

I'm kinda lost in here trying to get shindig (java) up and running...
I've downloaded the code from the svn repository (from trunk and other beta from tags) and I've been trying to install the code in the .m2 folder as a repository.

I did't succeed -.-
When I execute $ mvn in order to clean and install, it goes through the process until it reaches the 'Apache Shindig Gadget Renderer'. Trying to compile the project fails.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Shindig Project ............................ SUCCESS [3.004s]
[INFO] Apache Shindig Features ........................... SUCCESS [56.893s]
[INFO] Apache Shindig Common Code ........................ SUCCESS [20.824s]
[INFO] Apache Shindig Gadget Renderer .................... FAILURE [0.270s]
[INFO] Apache Shindig Social API ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Shindig Sample Container ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Shindig Web App Resources .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Shindig Extra Modules ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Shindig Web App Dependencies ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Shindig Web App ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The same happens if I use the eclipse plugin. I have the newest version of maven.
What's the problem here? Isn't it weird that the trunk (or any other beta) can compile? o.O

Thank's a lot in advance!

Comment: Without the error messages which had been produced it's not possible to guess into the right direction. Furhtermore don't exist those artifacts in a Maven repository? Do you have a special reason to download the source and build it yourself because this project is in Maven central.

Comment: Ok, I solved myself...
The thing is I had a proxy configurated in the settings.xml and it was there where the repository was searching for the modules...
I deleted the settings.xml and everything worked fine :)